# CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND ? in ros

Tags: python, cmake, simulator, ros

I am trying to install Morse 1.2 Stable version on my Ubuntu and I followed the steps which are mentioned in the manual installation of Morse. Following is the link :-
http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/1.2/user/installation.html

and when i tried to enter cmake .. command i get the following error:'

```
user@user-HP-ProBook-6550b:~/morse/build$ cmake ..
-- will install python files in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python3/dist-packages

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files: PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED) used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/src    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/src/morse    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/src/morse/builder    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/src/morse/modifiers    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/src/morse/sensors    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/src/morse/multinode    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/src/morse/middleware    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/bindings    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/testing    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/testing/base    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/testing/failures    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/testing/robots/human    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/testing/robots/rmax    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/testing/robots/segway    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/testing/robots/submarine    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/testing/robots/pr2    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/testing/robots/pionner3dx    used as include directory in directory /home/user/morse/testing/middlewares/ros

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: It seems CMake cannot find the python headers. Are you sure you installed `python-dev`? In case Morse is using the [standard find script for python](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPythonLibs.html), it will look for `Python.h` in the [system default directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_path.html), so make sure the file can be found there. Also, be aware that depending on your CMake and Python versions, you might have to set `Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS` before invoking the find script.